# syntax error: unexpected name, expecting semicolon or newline or }

Tags: go, compiler-errors

Just as a precursor I've just barely started learning Go recently. This is probably my 3rd day spending some time on it. I've been working with this error for a couple hours now, and I can't figure out what is wrong.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main () {
  nextFib := fibGenerator();
  fmt.Println(nextFib());
  fmt.Println(nextFib());
  fmt.Println(nextFib());
  fmt.Println(nextFib());
  fmt.Println(nextFib());
}

func fibGenerator () uint {
  var (
    n uint = 0
    back1 uint = 1
    back2 uint = 0
  )

  _computeFib := func () uint {
    if n == 0 {
      n++
      return 0
    } else if n == 1 {
      n++
      return 1
    }
    fib := 1back + 2back // throws compile time error on this line
    2back = 1back
    1back = n
    n++
    return fib
  }

  return _computeFib
}
```

This is the error it throws: 
syntax error: unexpected name, expecting semicolon or newline or }

It's probably something simple, but with my limited knowledge in Go I can't put my finger on it. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**:
This is the final working function besides renaming my variables like the accepted answer says I also had to make the generator return a function that returns an int. I also had an error w/ Fibonacci logic.

```
func fibGenerator () func() uint {
  var (
    n uint = 0
    back1 uint = 1
    back2 uint = 0
  )

  _computeFib := func () uint {
    if n == 0 {
      n++
      return 0
    } else if n == 1 {
      n++
      return 1
    }
    fib := back1 + back2
    back2 = back1
    back1 = fib
    n++
    return fib
  }

  return _computeFib
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access variables called `1back` and `2back` but your variables are actually called `back1` and `back2`

Comment: No problem. It happens :) Good thing there's a compiler catching these small mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Refactoring issues aside, keep in mind that variables in go must begin with a letter, not a number. `back1` and `back2` are valid go variables, but `1back` and `2back` are not. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Identifiers.